# Gradle copy: filesMatching(...) multiple files without a pattern

Tags: gradle

Gradle copy: filesMatching(multiple files) without a pattern. E.g.,

```
task copyFoo(type: Copy) {

   from ("/path") {
      filesMatching("foo.xml") {
         filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens : [VERSION, '1.2'])
      }

      filesMatching("bar.xml") {
         filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens : [VERSION, '1.2'])
      }

      filesMatching("hello.xml") {
         filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens : [VERSION, '1.2'])
      }
   }

}
```

Is there a way to merge them? like

```
      filesMatching("foo.xml" | "hello.xml" | "bar.xml") {
         filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens : [VERSION, '1.2'])
      }
```

Can the pattern be a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt about what you can do, head over to the [API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#filesMatching-java.lang.String-org.gradle.api.Action-). Here you will see that the `filesMatching` method takes a String, which describes an Ant pattern:

> ***CopySpec filesMatching​(String pattern,
> Action<? super FileCopyDetails> action)***
>
> Configure the FileCopyDetails for each file whose path matches the specified Ant-style pattern.

There are no methods that take a regex pattern. But there is an overloaded method that takes an iterable (like a list) of Ant patterns:

> ***CopySpec filesMatching​(Iterable<String> patterns,
> Action<? super FileCopyDetails> action)***
>
> Configure the FileCopyDetails for each file whose path matches any of the specified Ant-style patterns.

This means you can do:

```
filesMatching(["bar.xml", "hello.xml", "foo.xml"]) {
   filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens : [VERSION: '1.2'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#filtering_files

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
task copyFoo2(type: Copy) {
    from 'build/path'
    into "build/copy"
    include "foo.xml", "bar.xml", "hello.xml" 
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION: '1.2'])
}
```

Comment: This would exclude other files from being copied.